# Using summations to prove $s_{n+1}=s_n+s_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 2$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

I have this summation:

$$ s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n-k \choose k}$$

and I wanted to prove that $s_{n+1}=s_n+s_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 2$.

So to start of with I had $ s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n-k \choose k}$ and $s_{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-k-1 \choose k}$. I also found the identity that ${n-1 \choose k-1}+{n-1 \choose k}= {n\choose k}$.

But I am struggling to get any further to combine the two sums into one and rearrange to get $ s_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n-k+1 \choose k}$. Could anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's change the index $k\to k-1$ in the sum for  $s_{n-1}$. Let's do it step by step: Let $j=k+1$, so $k=j-1$. Making this substitution we get
$$s_{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1-k\choose k}=\sum_{j-1=0}^{n-1}{n-1-(j-1)\choose j-1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{n-j\choose j-1}.$$
we can just replace again $j$ by $k$ since this is just an index, so we have:
$$s_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n{n-k\choose k-1}.$$
So, \begin{align*}s_n+s_{n-1}&=\sum_{k=0}^n{n-k\choose k}+\sum_{k=1}^n{n-k\choose k-1}\\
&={n-0\choose 0}+\sum_{k=1}^n{n-k\choose k}+\sum_{k=1}^n{n-k\choose k-1}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^n{n-k\choose k}+{n-k\choose k-1}\end{align*}

Now, you can use your identity, getting  ${n-k\choose k}+{n-k\choose k-1}={n-k+1\choose k}$. So, $$s_n+s_{n-1}=1+\sum_{k=1}^n{n-k+1\choose k}$$

Now, convince yourself that the RHS  is $s_{n+1}$

Comment: How did you change the index in the first step?

Comment: I edited my answer, so it's more clear. Essentially if $0\leq k\leq n-1$, then $1\leq k+1\leq n$. I am making $j=k+1$ my new index.

Comment: This is perfect thank you!

Comment: Just another note, how did you change from $n-1$ to $n$ at the top of the summation in the first line?

Comment: It's practically same thing I said before. So, your sum is $0\leq j-1\leq n-1$, so $1\leq j\leq n$. I would encourage you to understand this things by actually writing all the terms of the sums and check that they coincide.